# Why can't a directory compressed with gzip, bzip, bzip2, xz?

Tags: linux, compression, archive

Is there any possible way to compress a directory with GZip, BZip, BZip2, xz format. I'm building a command line tool(using bash) which I need these options to be included.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46969/compress-a-folder-with-tar

Answer (score 1):

A command like

```
tar czf output.tar.gz yourdir/
```

should work.

- `c` means that `tar` will create an archive
- `z` means that the output will be compressed (using gzip)
- the output filename is after `f`
- at the end, you can specify any number of directories/files (space-separated)

Answer (score 1):

To answer the "why" part of your question, it is because of the Unix philosophy of having many small tools that do their job well that you can string together, as opposed to one big tool that doesn't do anything well and is hard to make better. Your examples are a perfect illustration of this philosophy, where you have several compression tools to choose from, and it is easy to add a new compression tool to your tool box. The archiving part, turning a directory of files into a byte stream, is a different task that is its own tool that can be combined with any of those or any future compression tools.

The body of your question then asks "how". You use a pipe with tar, cpio, or pax. tar is the most common. You then name the file accordingly so the consumer of the file can tell what it is from the name. E.g. ending with `.tar.gz`. Like this:

```
tar cf - somedirectory | gzip > somedirectory.tar.gz
```

or

```
tar cf - somedirectory | xz > somedirectory.tar.xz
```

These tar up the directory into a byte stream, which is then piped to a compressor. The output of the compressor is then written to the file containing the compressed directory contents.

To decompress:

```
gzip -dc somedirectory.tar.gz | tar xf -
```

Here it is done in the reverse order to first decompress the file and feed the output of that to tar to extract the files and recreate the directory structure. The `-` means to put the archive to stdout or get the archive from stdin.

Having said all that stuff about how much better it is to have small tools that do their job well, this application of tar is so incredibly common that it is built into the tar options. So you can instead:

```
tar czf somedirectory.tar.gz somedirectory

tar cJf somedirectory.tar.xz somedirectory
```

tar will run the gzip or xz executables and pipe the data through them itself.

(`J` is a recent gnutar addition, so your tar may not have it.)